# Formula for line that intersects two skew lines

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Given:

1. Two lines in $ℝ^3$ described by the vector equations:
   \begin{array}{lcl}
   \textbf{r}(t) & = & \textbf{r}_0+t\textbf{v} \\
   \textbf{s}(t) & = & \textbf{s}_0+t\textbf{w}
   \end{array}
2. The additional constraint that $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{s}$ are skew lines *(meaning, neither parallel nor intersecting)*.
3. An arbitrary vector $\textbf{u}$.

How can I construct a third line that...

1. has direction $\textbf{u}$, and
2. intersects both lines $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{s}$?

Can a general vector equation be derived for that third line?

Answer (score 1):

Let the intersection point with the first line be

$\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{r_0} + t \mathbf{v} $

and with the second line be

$\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{s_0} + s \mathbf{w} $

Then you want

$ \mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{P} = r \mathbf{u} $

The last equation can be written in matrix form as

$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} && - \mathbf{v} && - \mathbf{u} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \\ r \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{r_0} - \mathbf{s_0} $

Solve this system for the unknown $s, t, r $, then your line will be

$ \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{P} + t \mathbf{u}, \hspace{25pt} t \in \mathbb{R}$